# Is there a "symbol" on .NET that identify virtual-path?

Tags: asp.net, iis, webforms, virtual-path

Suppose this scenario. On my `Default.aspx`, I insert a context (WebForms), called `MyContext.ascx`, that load an image. So the path would be :

```
<img src="/images/hello.gif" />
```

Well. Now, I'd like to insert the same context on another .aspx page, that is in another forlder, such as `/myfolder/MyPage.aspx`

Than, the path of the image now should be :

```
<img src="../images/hello.gif" />
```

How you can see, I can't manage two different path for the same context. So, is there a way (symbol) to call the `virtual-path` of my application? Without using my own function as

```
<img src="<%=MyUtilities.GiveVirtualPath%>/images/hello.gif" />
```

which is boring. Who know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your images in the root of your web-site (and inside a resources/styles/themes folder).
You can use the tilde `~` to indicate the root of your site. All your pages will refer to that. If you're using server side controls you do not even need to use the `ResolvePath()` method (in your example you should use it, if for example you wrote asp:image ImageUrl="" you do not need to. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116.aspx).